# Windows batch file running all labels issue

Tags: windows, batch-file, label

I am having a weird issue with a windows batch file.

Here is a sample

```
call:label1
echo check1

:label1
echo label1

:label2
echo label2
```

The output I am expecting is

```
>label1
>check1
```

But the batch is running both labels and I am getting the following output:

```
>label1
>label2
>check1
```

I am calling the batch file from cmd. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Set EXIT or GOTO :EOF after each segment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labels just define a starting point. When a `call :label` instruction is used, called code is executed from this starting point until reaching the end of the batch file. So, to end a subroutine before the next one is reached (and return to the calling point), you will need to add an `exit /b` or `goto :eof` or whatever other jump to the end of the batch file, as

```
call:label1
echo check1
goto endOfWork

:label1
echo label1
goto :eof

:label2
echo label2
exit /b

:endOfWork
```

`:eof` is an implicit label that points to the EndOfFile, and does not need to be declared.

So, `goto :eof` is a jump to the end of the file.

`exit /b` is just the same, a jump to the end of file.

The `:endOfWork` is a user defined label (the same you are using in your code) than i'm using to get the same result without using the previous instructions.

Comment: My issue is i need to run echo check1 after label1 is run. Check my answer to my own question for a workaround

Comment: @yash, and it will. When you call a subroutine, the way to return to the calling point is to reach the end of the batch file. When it is reached, execution continues on the line after the `call` instruction

Comment: you are right. Shame to me to talk without testing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My issue here is that I need the next line, that is `echo check1` to run after the label1 call. I cannot `goto :eof` or `exit /b` in label1. My workaround here is:

```
call:label1
echo check1

:label1
echo label1

:label2
if %1 =="running" (
   echo label2
)
```

Therefore, to call label2 you will have to pass the parameter `call :label2 running`. Calling label1 will not run anything in the if clause of the label 2. Looks a bit dirty to me but I could not find any way round.

Comment: When you call a subroutine, the way to return to the calling point is to reach the end of the batch file, so, to get the desired result you should include a `goto :eof`, `exit /b`, or other jump to reach the end of batch file.